Network won't work after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade
I upgraded my 22.04 LTS desktop to 24.04.1 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 15 3520, and it failed at the end. I booted from a USB drive and was able to finish the installation, but I'm getting Network Unavailable (can't access my Wi-Fi and have no ethernet board).
I tried to reinstall systemd-resolved locally (downloaded from another PC), but it didn't work.
Tried this, also didn't work.
I've read here that NetworkManager and systemd-enable are incompatible, and tried keeping just one of them enabled (did it for both), but it didn't work.
systemctl restart [service] for both NetworkManager and systemd-resolved returns:
Job for [service] failed because a fatal signal was delivered causing the control process to dump core.
See "systemctl status [service]" and "journalctl -xeu [service]" for details.

Results of sudo lshw -C network :
    *-network DISABLED              
             description: Wireless interface
             product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
             vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
             physical id: 0
             bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
             logical name: wlp2s0
             version: 00
             serial: fc:b0:de:7f:fc:21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: irq:149 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:70800000-7080ffff

Results of lspci | grep Network ;
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Results of systemctl status systemd-resolved.service:
× systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
         Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; preset: en>
         Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Fri 2024-09-06 13:51:41 -03; 59s ago
             Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
                         man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
                         https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configurati>
                         https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
        Process: 3965 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved (code=dumped, signal=SYS)
     Main PID: 3965 (code=dumped, signal=SYS)
                CPU: 25ms

set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart>
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too qui>
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-resolved.service - Network Name >

results of journalctl -xeu systemd-resolved.service :
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Main process exited, code=dump>
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

An ExecStart= process belonging to unit systemd-resolved.service has exited.

The process' exit code is 'dumped' and its exit status is 31.
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit systemd-resolved.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump>
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-resolved.service - Network Name >
Subject: A start job for unit systemd-resolved.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit systemd-resolved.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 3967 and the job result is failed.
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart>
Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Automatic restarting of the unit systemd-resolved.service has been scheduled, as the re>
the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too qui>
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit systemd-resolved.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump>
set 06 13:51:41 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-resolved.service - Network Name >
Subject: A start job for unit systemd-resolved.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit systemd-resolved.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 3979 and the job result is failed.

Results of systemctl status NetworkManager :
× NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
         Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enab>
         Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Fri 2024-09-06 13:51:22 -03; 1min 42s ago
             Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
        Process: 3913 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
     Main PID: 3913 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
                CPU: 29ms

set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart c>
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quick>
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
set 06 13:51:28 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quick>
set 06 13:51:28 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
set 06 13:51:28 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.

Results of journalctl -xeu NetworkManager :
Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 3601 and the job result is failed.
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart c>
Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Automatic restarting of the unit NetworkManager.service has been scheduled, as the resu>
the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quick>
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump'.
set 06 13:51:22 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 3707 and the job result is failed.
set 06 13:51:28 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quick>
set 06 13:51:28 marco systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump'.
set 06 13:51:28 marco systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.
 
The job identifier is 3813 and the job result is failed.


see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1519273/1698042
